# Swift delegate calling fatal error

Tags: swift, delegates

I am trying to call a delegate function in Swift 3.0. While calling i am getting an error which states "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I have gone through giving static values, dynamic values no use.

```
 protocol getServiceDelegate{
    func getService(_ ServiceTitle: String)

}
```

And i call this delegate in following manner.

```
 self.delegate.getService("hello")
```

What i am doing here wrong. Below which i set the delegate.

```
func textServiceTapped(img: AnyObject)
{
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProviderMoreDetailsVC") as! ProviderMoreDetailsViewController

    vc.delegate = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc,
                                             animated: true)

}

func getService(_ ServiceTitle: String){
    textService.text = ServiceTitle

}
```

Comment: May be you forgot to set the delegate where are implementing it.

Comment: No, already set the delegate

Comment: Then you need to show the code of that also.

Comment: Check the outlet of `textService` is properly connected.

Comment: Its already connected

Comment: Add this line `print(self.delegate)` before line `self.delegate.getService("hello")` and check what is output in console.

Comment: please write `ServiceTitle` with first letter lowercased because it is not a class name

Comment: give some more code it can help more.

Comment: Delegate seems nill first time

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the error by using below code

```
var delegate: getServiceDelegate?
 sampleDelegateString = "hello"
 self.delegate?.getService(sampleDelegateString!)
```